# GNU/Emacs for gtk+ programming

Tags: emacs, gtk

I want to start C/gtk+ programming in GNU/Emacs. Where can i find manual, how to configure GNU/Emacs for C and gtk+ programming. I want to make GNU/Emacs IDE for gtk+ programming

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Gtk+, but you could use [CEDET](http://cedet.sf.net) + [company-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompanyMode) or [auto-complete](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete) to do this - at least it works fine with standard C/C++ libraries

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any particular setup. cc-mode is probably all you'll need, but if you'd like to create some fancier environment, you'd probably want to heed Alex's suggestion.